# Order by custom post meta date

Tags: wordpress, date, custom-post-type

I'm trying to order my upcoming events by custom post meta date, but it's not working as it should. It orders by days only and ignores months and years.
example:

1st April 2016 
4th July 2016 
10th May 2016

```
<?php
global $post;

 $today = date('jS F Y');
    $args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'event',
            'posts_per_page'    => 4,
            'meta_key'          => 'start_date', 
            'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
            'order'             => 'DESC',
            'meta_value_num'    => $today,
            'meta_compare'      => '>'
  );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

echo '<ul class="events-list">';
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
echo '<li>';
echo '<div class="meta-fields">';
$start_date = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'start_date', true );
$new_format_start = date_i18n('jS F Y',strtotime($start_date)); 
$end_date = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'end_date', true ); 
echo  $new_format_start;

    if ($end_date) {
    $new_format_end = date_i18n('jS F Y',strtotime($end_date)); 
    echo ' - ' . $new_format_end;
    } else {
    echo "";
    } 
echo '</div>';
?>
<p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>

<div class="entry-content">
     <p class="event-widget"> <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?> </p>
</div>
</li>

<?php 
    endwhile;
    echo '</ul>';
    }
```

Comment: Specify type parameter like this 'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC'  but your date format should be  like this date("Y-m-d");

Comment: I've tried that, but it didn't work :/

Comment: try this link i hope its useful for your requirement.

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178156/order-by-three-custom-fields-y-m-d-then-separate-into-yearly-sections

Comment: Sadly that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay apparently it didn't work because I was using a datepicker in my input, so I changed it to 
 `<input type="date">`. 
 Too bad input date doesn't work in firefox.